# GORM methods are not accessible in Domain and Service classes 

Tags: grails-orm, grails-2.0

**UPDATED:**

I have installed grails 2.0 
I have got two Domain classesApplicationConfiguration   and City ,
ApplicationConfiguration  stores the defaults fields and their values 
City will access the ApplicationConfiguration   value

```
class ApplicationConfiguration {
    String myDefaultField
    String value

    static getMyDefaultCity(){
        def city_id  =  ApplicationConfiguration.findByMyDefaultField('city') .id
        def  cityName = ApplicationConfiguration.get(city_id ).value
    } 
}


Class City{
    def ApplicationConfiguration
    String city = ApplicationConfiguration.getMyDefaultCity()
}
```

Basically I am not able to access the GORM Methods form the Domain and Service such as
1) executeQuery()
2) find*()

And I get the error as below

```
  ... 5 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectCity
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        ... 5 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ApplicationConfiguration.findByMyDefaultFie
ld() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [city]
        at ApplicationConfiguration.getMyDefaultCity(ApplicationConfiguration.groovy:63)
        at City.<init>(City.groovy:28)
```

and when i do `ApplicationConfiguration.findByMyDefaultField('city')` in my controller it works fine, GORM Methods are accessible in controllers

The test case to reproduce the bug is

```
1) Create a project using grails project wizard
2) Create two domain classes ApplicationConfiguration(String myDefaultField, String value) and City(String city) 
3) Do generate-all for  ApplicationConfiguration
4) Now add this "getMyDefaultCity()" with the definition method as shown above
5) Initialize the filed city in City domain class "String city = ApplicationConfiguration.getMyDefaultCity()"
6) Restart the application
```

Comment: btw, did you restart the app and try? i've seen similar errors after modifying domain classes and before restarting

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this question could be useful to you: [Adding business logic to a domain class using a getter style method name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920250/adding-business-logic-to-a-domain-class-using-a-getter-style-method-name)

Have you used a transient declaration for the method?